# I need simplify jdbc connection in my java ee app. I want to rewrite in Spring.It creates too much static connections

Tags: java, mysql, spring, exception, jdbc

I have 1 MySQL URL and 4 databases (schemas) with same table names but different count of rows (I mean it's not simple to union them). In my java application I have a method which chooses database connection by some (my own) condition. Than create object with chosen url in argument. But I think it is not correct.

For example

```
jdbc:mysql://123.456.789.10:3306/First_Database
jdbc:mysql://123.456.789.10:3306/Second_Database
jdbc:mysql://123.456.789.10:3306/Third_Database
jdbc:mysql://123.456.789.10:3306/Fourth_Database
```

Example of connection

```
public static void createConnectionFirst() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        connect_1 = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user, password);
    }// and then same methods for connect_2 connect_3 and connect_4
```

And when I locally shut down, I get exception:

```
14-Nov-2019 17:25:34.774 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await A valid shutdown command was received via the shutdown port. Stopping the Server instance.
14-Nov-2019 17:25:34.774 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
14-Nov-2019 17:25:34.879 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
14-Nov-2019 17:25:34.960 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
14-Nov-2019 17:25:34.976 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [sc] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis(Native Method)
 org.apache.catalina.webresources.CachedResource.validateResource(CachedResource.java:82)
 org.apache.catalina.webresources.Cache.getResource(Cache.java:87)
 org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getResource(StandardRoot.java:216)
 org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.getClassLoaderResource(StandardRoot.java:225)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLenter code hereoaderBase.java:936)
 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1055)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:96)
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:69)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
14-Nov-2019 17:25:34.976 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
14-Nov-2019 17:25:34.976 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
14-Nov-2019 17:25:34.976 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8088"]
14-Nov-2019 17:25:34.976 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Disconnected from server
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use Tomcat it is possible to pre-configure all of your datasource inside the [context.xml](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html) file with following (example from tomcat manual):

```
  <Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
           maxTotal="100" maxIdle="30" maxWaitMillis="10000"
           username="javauser" password="javadude" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
           url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest"/>
```

since that Tomcat is responsible for managing connections and it decides either to open or close it as needed.

In your code you just searching for Datasource with particular name and use it.
See tomcat [manual on how to configure datasources](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html)